# Is CORS still enforced when method is marked AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, webapi

For WebApi Core 2.2, if an endpoint has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, is CORS still enforced for that endpoint?  If not, is there a way to enforce CORS?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of AllowAnonymous has no affect on CORS. AllowAnonymous instructs that the end point can be accessed by any one thus no authentication is required.

CORS deals with cross origin requests made through script for instance Ajax calls. For instance an ajax call from https://domain1 to https://domain2 will be failed if domain2 wont enable CORS for the request from the domain1. The CORS also fails if you make a call from http to https.

Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to learn more about CORS.